# Can two parameters with the same name be passed to a service?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

I'm passing parameters to a server from a Flash Builder application. I want to search both for "teachers" and for "rooms". I can do this via an HTML page, as follows:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="searchFor" value="teachers" />teachers 
<input type="checkbox" name="searchFor" value="rooms" />rooms
```

So there are two inputs, both named searchFor. When submitted, the request looks like this:

```
searchFor: teachers
searchFor: rooms
```

In other words, two parameters are passed.

I'm trying to do the same thing in Flash Builder using an object called param:

```
param.query = pQuery;
param.searchFor = "teachers";
param.searchFor = "rooms";
searchUsersService(param);
```

Flex overwrites the one with the other, as I suspected it would, so all that is submitted is "rooms".  Is it possible to pass two parameters with the same name? (or do I need to ask the server guys to rename their search parameters?)

Thanks.

Comment: I'd just send param.searchFor = "teachers, rooms"; and have the backend resolve the comma delimited string.

Comment: I'd go the other direction and rename the params. That's a mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. It will only override the previous value:

```
param.query = pQuery;
param.searchFor = "teachers";
param.searchFor = "rooms";    //Will obviously override the previous value
searchUsersService(param);
```

What you can do is:

```
param.searchFor = [ "teachers", "rooms" ];
```

Or

```
param.searchFor = new ArrayCollection();
param.searchFor.add( "teachers" );
param.searchFor.add( "rooms" );
```

And then in the server side you can get all the values from your array.

Comment: I used the array solution and it works fine. Thanks! And you look so young!

Comment: Yes and very unhappy for some reason :) glad I helped